# Change color of a most controls (ie TPanel) in a Firemonkey Mobile in Delphi XE6

Tags: mobile, styles, firemonkey

Many controls like TPanel and so on, do not support a simple way to change color of any element.

The **standard Firemonkey Application** use the "Styles" feature.
(rx click on the component and choose Edit Custom Style)

But into **Firemonkey Mobile Application**, it's impossible customize the style.
(if you rx click on the component, "Edit Custom Style" is missing)

For example, how to change the background color of TPanel?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the TPanel with a TRectangle (which is all that a TPanel is anyway).

For other controls use the Tint property that is introduced in XE6.